# How to catch new thread in gdb console mode?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, debugging

I am running my Qt app from gdb, and i want to stop when new threads creates.
(when gdb prints message `[New Thread address (LPW number)`].

I have set breakpoint `b __pthread_create_2_1`.
That allows me to catch most of new threads prints. but i still got few new threads that are not catched.
What else can i do to catch their creation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably what you want is
`catch syscall clone` (see here https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html)

Also by default gdb let other threads continue their execution if a breakpoint or catchpoint event occurs.
So maybe you want to take a look at the All-Stop mode (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Thread-Stops.html)